# Autolayout of 2 multiline UILabels

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, autolayout

I'm making an "Latest news" XIB that I will reuse through my storyboard.

The thing is that the XIB file is for some reason having a much greater height than it should. 
I have tried using `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` or setting the height constraint to be `a >= x` but nothing worked.

Here is my view hierarchy, and the constraints of the views:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The result is this:

[image]

Here is the hierarchy of the storyboard scene:
[image]

I hope this is enough information, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to set the background color of the three labels, to figure out which one is breaking your layout

Comment: Also, as I can tell from your storyboard you have some conflicting constraints (the red arrow) and unambiguous layout (the yellow dashed lines). Make sure all your AutoLayout guides are blue and you have no warnings or errors. These should hopefully point you in the right direction

Comment: You are using the "compact-regular" size class. Is that the correct class for your device? Do you have the wrong constraints set in a different size class?

Comment: @GrahamPerks Yes that is the correct size class.

@Aleksander I have colored them. It's the middle (category) label that is making the problem. But just for debugging purposes I have set it's height to a fixed value, and then the top (headline) label's height is too big. In the end, if I set the height to be fixed for the top label, the bottom one is making the same problems.
The warnings I have are [here](http://i.imgur.com/mw5W2t7.png):
Also, in the storyboard, for the UIView of the latest news, I have set its intrinsic size to `placeholder`.

Comment: have you make nooflines = 0 ?

Comment: @VDPatel Yes, the top and the bottom labels have `numberOfLines = 0`, and the middle one has `numberOfLines = 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `Content Hugging Priority` and the `Content Compression Resistance Priority`weren't correctly set, so the UIImageView on the left was always expanding to its maximum height.

The problem was gone once the `Content Priorities` were set so the text on the right was determining the height of the container.

Answer (score 0):

My guess from looking at your nib layouts is that the top level Container is constrained to the top and bottom of it's super view. That constraint is probably beating out the other constraints.
Break those constraints and see if that helps.